# HTACCESS redirection with parameters not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to rewrite url on my PHP website but I'm not sure about the syntax.

I want to redirect :

```
'some_url?id=1' => 'new_url/1'
```

And when user type this :

`'new_url/1'`

I want him to be backend redirect to :

```
'some_url?id=1'
```

---

**UPDATE:** My last try:

```
RewriteRule /site/?id=$1    /site/$1
```

Comment: I'm a rewriting noob, last try : 'RewriteRule /site/?id=$1 /site/$1'

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+some_url\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /new_url/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^new_url/(.+?)/?$ some_url?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't match the query string in rewrite rules. You need to use a rewrite condition instead.

Stuff matched there with `()` can then be used in the rewrite rule with the `%n` notation (as opposed to `$n`.

So what you are looking for is something along these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^some_url($|/) /new_url/%1?
```

Demo here:

http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=0e31a7bf-9711-533d-896b-461177c46ca2

Comment: However, you'll need an additional _condition_ to prevent a redirect/rewrite loop when rewriting back to the "real" URL. One way is to check against `THE_REQUEST` (instead of `QUERY_STRING`), as Croises has done in his answer, or check against `ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS`.